# Inexplicable <br> pops up in the middle of a PHP-script

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this code:

```
if ($type == 'banner') {

        $page1 = $lines['89'] . '<br /><br />';
        $page2 = str_replace("'value' => '", '', $page1);
        $page3 = str_replace("',", '', $page2);
        $page4 = str_replace(" ", '', $page3);
        $page = '-'. $page4;

        $name = strtolower($tnid_title);
        $name = str_replace(' ', '-', $name);
        $name = str_replace('/', '-', $name);
        $name = 'profiles/exports/' . $type . '/' . $name;
        $name .= $language == 'und' ? '' : ('-' . $language);
        $name .= $page;
        $name .= '.php';
        return $name;
    }
```

And for some reason, it returns this:

```
/exports/banner/banner1-homepage
<br>
<br>
.php"
<br>
/exports/banner/banner1-homepage
<br>
<br>
.php'
```

Where do these two `<br>` come from?

Comment: What are you trying to do by the way? Seems whatever it is there will be a much easier way to get Drupal to do this for you :)

Comment: What is in `$lines`? The only place I can see any `<br>` tags entering into this is in `$page1 = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here: `$page1 = $lines['89'] . '<br /><br />';`. None of the rest of your code removes them, so they'll be carried through the string search/replace/building sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I would think they come from:

```
    $page1 = $lines['89'] . '<br /><br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess from this line:

```
$page1 = $lines['89'] . '<br /><br />';
```